# How to write a script that will calculate an interest rate

Tags: javascript, forms

I am building a form using the WP plugin called Calculated Fields Form.
The first question is for people to enter the amount they want to invest (fieldname2)

The second question is for people to select the number of months (fieldname3)
Based on the amount and the length, a different interest rate should be displayed.

I am supposed to enter the equation myself so I wrote the following script to try but it doesn't work.

```
(function()`{`
if (50<=fieldname2<=99 && fieldname3=3) return fieldname2*4/100;
if (50<=fieldname2<=99 && fieldname3=6) return fieldname2*6/100;
if (50<=fieldname2<=99 && fieldname3=12) return fieldname2*8/100;
`}`)();
```

Comment: Syntax errors... `50<=fieldname2<=99` isn't a valid comparison and `fieldname3=3` is an _assignment_, not an equality comparison. You want `if (50 <= fieldname2 && fieldname2 <= 99 && fieldname3 === 3)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to achieve here but the issues with your code are as follows:

```
(function()`{`
// --------^^^ unexpected template string
if (50<=fieldname2<=99 && fieldname3=3) return fieldname2*4/100;
// ------^^^ this is not valid  ----^^^ should be === not =
if (50<=fieldname2<=99 && fieldname3=6) return fieldname2*6/100;
if (50<=fieldname2<=99 && fieldname3=12) return fieldname2*8/100;
`}`)();
// immediately invoked function - but why?
// what happens if "50<=fieldname2<=99" is not satisfied?
```

A bit of advice - write the function first as a testable entity to see if it is even getting the result you want. Use expressive arguments so you can reason about what you are doing. Consider cases that are not covered by your function (see comments below). In those cases, you will return `undefined` which I doubt is desirable.

```
function calculateInterest (amount, months) {
  if (50 <= amount && amount <= 99) {
    if (months === 3) return amount*4/100;
    if (months === 6) return amount*6/100;
    if (months === 12) return amount*8/100;
    // what should we return if months does not satisfy one of the above?
  }
  // what should we return if amount does not satisfy the above?
}
```

Assuming `fieldname2` and `fieldname3` are variables that exist in your code, you can now call the function `calculateInterest(fieldname2, fieldname3)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, fieldname2 and fieldname3 are variables that already exist. 'months' will always satisfy any of the 3 I mentioned, because on the form, people can only select from 3 radio buttons (3 months, 6 months or 12 months). However, if the amount is different, I need to display a different rate. For example, for 3 months, if 50<=amount<=99, then the rate should be 1% but if 100<=amount<=499, the rate should be 3%. I have set a minimum of 50 for the amount and a maximum of 10,000 so if people try to enter anything less than 50 or more than 10,000, an error message will appear.

Comment: @evos89 ok so we can eliminate the first comment since there are only 3 options for month. In terms of the rate, how does that affect the formula you have listed? For example, 50<=amount<=99 with month 6 yields amount*6/100. What would 100<=amount<=499 yield with month 6?

Can you provide the original formula you are trying to reproduce here?

Comment: Actually, there is no formula, the rates are fixed values.

Comment: @evos89 In that case are you still stuck on something or did you get the code working?